# RTC Work Ticket Failing Creation - 'Owned By' Attribute Needs to be Set

Tags: rdf, rational-team-concert, ibm-jazz, oslc

I'm trying to generate a Build Ticket in RTC via a post to our Jazz server. When I do, I'm always met with the error that I need to set the 'Owned By' attribute. As far as I can tell from documentation, dcterms:contributor is the owner. I've tried making up a "dcterms:ownedBy" and "dcterms:OwnedBy" and "dc:OwnedBy" etc, but nothing works. Why doesn't it like it??

**What I'm Sending:**

```xml
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" 
         xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" 
         xmlns:rtc_cm="http://jazz.net/xmlns/prod/jazz/rtc/cm/1.0/" 
         xmlns:rtc_ext="http://jazz.net/xmlns/prod/jazz/rtc/ext/1.0/">
   <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="A0">
      <dcterms:contributor rdf:resource="https://[host]/jts/users/[user_id]" />
      <rtc_cm:due rdf:dataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">2020-06-24T16:00:00.000Z</rtc_cm:due>
...
```

**Response:**

```xml
<rdf:RDF
  xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
  xmlns:oslc="http://open-services.net/ns/core#">
    <oslc:Error rdf:about="#n0">
        <oslc:message>'Save Work Item' failed. Preconditions have not been met: The 'Owned By' attribute needs to be set (work item &lt;08:54:54&gt;).</oslc:message>
        <oslc:statusCode>403</oslc:statusCode>
    </oslc:Error>
    <rdf:Description rdf:about="https://[host]/ccm/oslc/contexts/[project-key]/workitems/[build.item]">
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, the error was lying. If any of the attributes are incorrectly set up, I will get the preconditions error for "Owned By" not being set. In the end, I had a couple attributes wrong. In the example above, the rtc_cm:due was wrong for having rdf:dataType in the tag. Or at least something was wrong with that part of the tag. Removing it made it work fine.